# Show that $E(|S_n-np|) = 2vq b(v; n, p) $.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> (Feller Vol.1, P.241, Q.35) Let $S_n$ be the number of successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials. Prove
> $$E(|S_n-np|) = 2vq b(v; n, p) $$
> where $v$ is the integer such that $np < v \le np+1$ and $b(v; n,p)$ is a binomial distribution with $v$ successes of $n$ trials. Hint: The left side $= \sum_{k=0}^{v-1} (np - k) \frac{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}$.

My attempt: I found that $P(|S_n - np| = j)= b(np +j ; n, p)$ if $S_n \ge np$, $b(np-j; n,p)$ if $S_n < np$. Therefore,
$$E(|S_n-np|)= \sum_{k=0}^{v-1} (np-k)b(k;n,p) + \sum_{k=v}^{n}(k-np)b(k; n,p).$$

I am stuck here, and don't know how to proceed. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: In the hint, do you mean $\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ k\end{array}\right)$ instead of $\frac{n}{k}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be tempted to take this hint and see how I can simplify it first. And by simplify I mean get rid of the summation. So we have
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{v-1}(np-k)\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ k\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k} \\
=&np\sum_{k=0}^{v-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ k\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}-n\sum_{k=1}^{v-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}
\end{align*}
using the identity $\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ k\end{array}\right)=\frac{n}{k}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)$ which is easy to prove, and which should often be in the back of your head when you have these combination expressions multiplied by $n$ or $k$. I replace $k=0$ with $k=1$ in the second sum also as the substitution is only valid when $k\geq 1$ and the $k=0$ term contributed nothing to the sum anyway.

Now we don't know how to sum any of these really, unless they refer to an expectation or probability. If I'd kept the $k$ in the second sum it would look more like an expectation but as the sum is partial it will never be one, which is what motivated me to replace it with $n$ which can be removed from the sum. It's easy to see that the first sum is $\mathbb{P}[S_n\leq v-1]$, it would be nice if we could make the second sum look similar. It would have to be a probability related to $S_{n-1}$; see that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{v-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}&=\sum_{l=0}^{v-2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ l\end{array}\right)p^{l+1}q^{n-(l+1)} \\
&=p\sum_{l=0}^{v-2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ l\end{array}\right)p^{l}q^{n-1-l} \\
&=p\mathbb{P}[S_{n-1}\leq v-2]. 
\end{align*}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
np\sum_{k=0}^{v-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ k\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}-n\sum_{k=1}^{v-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}
&=np\left(\mathbb{P}[S_n\leq v-1]-\mathbb{P}[S_{n-1}\leq v-2]\right).
\end{align*}
It's annoying that these probabilities are for different variables, but consider the following. If, instead of being independent variables, $S_{n-1}$ was the number of successes in $n-1$ trials and $S_n$ was the number of successes in $n$ trials, and these trials were from the $\textbf{same sequence}$, then by sketching a Venn diagram if necessary we can see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[S_n\leq v-1]-\mathbb{P}[S_{n-1}\leq v-2]=&\mathbb{P}[S_{n-1}=v-1,\;n\text{-th trial is a failure}] \\
=&\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ v-1\end{array}\right)p^{v-1}q^{n-1-(k-1)}q
\end{align*}
so that ultimately we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\vert S_n-np\vert]=np\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1 \\ v-1\end{array}\right)p^{v-1}q^{n-1-(v-1)}q=vq\left(\begin{array}{cc} n \\ v\end{array}\right)p^vq^{n-v}=vqb(v;n,p),
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: It's possible there's a more algebraic way to finish this off rather than by relying on dependent random variables which kind of comes out of left field, but it's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that you takes the hint as given. Do you know why $E[|S_n - np|] = \sum_{k=0}^{v-1} (np-k) {n \choose k} p^k q^{n-k}$ at the first place? (by the way, I agree that it it is ${n \choose k}$ instead of $\frac{n}{k}$. I guess the author made errata.)

Comment: On re-reading, I don't agree with the hint and I've also missed the 2 in the answer. I think the hint should say that $\mathbb{E}\vert S_n- np\vert=\sum_{k=0}^{v-1}(np-k)\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\ k\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}+\sum_{k=v}^{n}(k-np)\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\ k\end{array}\right)p^kq^{n-k}$, which is self-evident by the definition of $v$ and the nature of absolute values. And I'd imagine you could show that the second sum is also equal to $vqb(v;n,p)$, which makes up for the 2 I have missing in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The hint given is not quite correct as mentioned by @PepeSilvia.

For any random variable $X$ with finite mean $\mu$, we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X-\mu|]&=\mathbb E[|X-\mu|I_{X>\mu}]+\mathbb E[|X-\mu|I_{X\le\mu}]
\\&=\mathbb E[(X-\mu )I_{X>\mu}]+\mathbb E[(\mu-X )I_{X\le\mu}] \tag{1}
\end{align}

But $\mathbb E(X-\mu )=0$, so

$$0=\mathbb E[(X-\mu)I_{X>\mu}]+\mathbb E[(X-\mu)I_{X\le\mu}]$$

That is, $$\mathbb E[(X-\mu)I_{X>\mu}]=\mathbb E[(\mu-X)I_{X\le\mu}] \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that

$$\mathbb E[|X-\mu|]=2\,\mathbb E[(X-\mu)I_{X>\mu}]=2\,\mathbb E[(\mu-X)I_{X\le\mu}]$$

So a direct calculation here would involve evaluating $$\mathbb E[|S_n-np|]=2\sum_{j=v}^n (j-np) f(j)=2\sum_{j=0}^{v-1} (np-j) f(j)\,,\tag{3}$$

where $f(j)=\binom{n}{j}p^jq^{n-j}$ and $v=\lfloor np \rfloor +1$.

But this can be done here without much work.

We have the relation

$$\frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)}=\left(\frac{n-j}{j+1}\right)\frac{p}{q} \quad,\, j=0,1,\ldots,n$$

That is, $$q(j+1)f(j+1)=npf(j)-pjf(j) \quad,\, j=0,1,\ldots,n$$

Therefore, $$q\sum_{j=v}^n (j+1)f(j+1)=np\sum_{j=v}^n f(j)-p\sum_{j=v}^n jf(j)$$

Noting that $f(n+1)=0$, this is same as $$q\sum_{j=v}^n jf(j)-q vf(v)=np\sum_{j=v}^n f(j)-p\sum_{j=v}^n jf(j)$$

That is, $$\sum_{j=v}^n jf(j)-np\sum_{j=v}^n f(j)=q vf(v) \tag{4}$$

So from $(3)$ and $(4)$ we end up with

$$\mathbb E[|S_n-np|]=2\left[\sum_{j=v}^n jf(j)-np\sum_{j=v}^n f(j)\right]=2vqf(v)$$

(Working with the other sum $\sum_{j=0}^{v-1} (np-j) f(j)$ also results in the same answer).

This can be seen as a general method for finding mean absolute deviation about mean (if it exists) of a non-negative discrete distribution whenever the probability mass function $f$ is such that $$\frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)}=\frac{\alpha+\beta j}{j+1}\quad,\,j=0,1,\ldots$$ for some constant $\alpha,\beta$.