# Let $X\sim B(n,p)$. How to calculate the expected value $E[\bar{X}]$,where $\bar{X}=|X-E[X]|$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X\sim B(n,p)$. How to calculate the the expected value $E[\bar{X}]$,where $\bar{X}=|X-E[X]|$?

Recently I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(n)&=\frac1nE[\bar{X}] = \frac1nE[|X-np|]=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n}[C_n^i p^i (1-p)^{n-i}|i - np|]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
is decreasing over $\mathbb{Z}^+$, so need to know how to calculate the expected value $E[\bar{X}]$. Of course, I would also really appreciate it if you know how to prove it.

---

Edited on July 16, 2022

The previous $f(n)$ missed a coefficient of $\frac1n$. After correction, I can already prove that $f(n)$ is decreasing over $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

The left side of the following figure is the image of $E[\bar{X}]$, and the right side is the image of the current $f(n)$.

[image: figure]

Comment: The Law of the Unconscious Statistician says that you do not need to know how $\bar X$ is distributed .   $$\mathsf E[g(X)]=\sum_{i=0}^n g(i)\,\mathsf P(X=i)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3720012/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Theorem** (de Moivre, 1730): If $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, then $$
> \begin{align}E|X-np|
> &=2\lceil np\rceil(1-p)\cdot P(X=\lceil np\rceil)\\
> &=2\lceil np\rceil\binom{n}{\lceil np\rceil}p^{\lceil np \rceil}(1-p)^{n-\lceil np \rceil+1}.\end{align}$$

See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2245429 for a reference, or [this stats.stackexchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147771) for a proof.